# Searching takes user directly to a page?

Tags: magento2, search

When searching on our site, some reason the user is sometimes sent directly to a page (kind of like Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" but random and even less helpful) instead of the search results page.

Any ideas on where to look or what to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Debug the search action and see what is happening.

Comment: @vitoriodachef how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Im using Smile ElasticSuite for searching in Magento 2, and there is on option, "**Redirect to product page if only one result**." This enables or disables, `If there is only one product matching a given search query, the user will be redirect to this product page.` This sounds like your behavior and could lead you in the right direction.

To get there you goto:

`Stores -> Configuration -> Smile Elasticsuite -> Catalog Search`